# Loading html page in jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load html page inside jquery dialog but it does not work. below is my jquery code. "openTerms" function is triggered when there is click in link. it opens up the dialog but give me resource not found error. however "terms.html" reside in the project and added as item.

```
 <a id="someclientid" name="someuniqueid" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openTerms();">Terms and Conditions</a> 


    <script>
            function openTerms()
    {
        pathArray = location.href.split( '/' );
        protocol = pathArray[0];
        host = pathArray[2];
        url =  pathArray[0] + '//' + pathArray[1]  + '//' + pathArray[2] + '//' + pathArray[3] 

        url = url + "/Orchard.Club" + "/terms.html";

        var page = url;

        alert(url);

        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                       .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                       .dialog({
                           autoOpen: false,
                           modal: true,
                           height: 700,
                           width: 1100,
                           title: "Terms and Conditions",
                           buttons: {                                   
                               Cancel: function () {
                                   $(this).dialog("close");
                               }
                           },

                           close: function () { setFormControls(); },
                           open: function () {

                           }

                       });

        $dialog.dialog('open');
    }

</script>
```

}

Answer (score 1):

After loading the contents you need to show the dialog box

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    $("#dialog").html(data).dialog('open');
});
```

---

Also try the load() method load content like

```
$("#dialog").load(url, function(){
    $(this).dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: i am able to open dialog  but give me resource not found error. however "terms.html" reside in the project and added as item. see my modified post

Comment: i need to open a file that is added to current project e.g. terms.html should be opened in jquery dialog? how can i achieve this?